# Video made from rotating the initial cube

Tags: animation

I would like to create a video which would show the rotating cube as I rotated it with my mouse (I know how to rotate it by now!).
And a hint from where I can start creating it and also replay it.

[image]

Comment: There is a lot to learn about animation and I think it is important to look up tutorials on the subject. In order to create a video like this you will need to learn about inserting key frames within the timeline which is at the bottom of your screen. A good tutorial to help with this is The Complete Beginners Guide to Animation by Grant Abbitt. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp6kCe5Kmf4

Comment: It sounds like you want your mouse cursor in the final render. If so, it might be easiest to simply rotate your cube in the viewport as normal, but while running a separate screen recording program in the background, which will directly capture all your on-screen interactions.